# Why Bootstrap icons does not work in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

I don't know why bootstrap icons doesn't work in ReactJS.

[Here is my buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPuSp.png)

My post items code:

import React from 'react';

```
const PostListItem = () => {
    return (
        <li className="app-list-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span className="app-list-item-label">
                Hello World!!
            </span>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <button className="btn-star btn-sm">
                    <i className="f fa-star"></i>
                </button>
                <button className="btn-trash btn-sm">
                    <i className="f fa-trash-o"></i>
                </button>
                <i className="f fa-trash-heart"></i>

            </div>
        </li>
    );
};

export default PostListItem;
```

My index.hmtl  where put a link to https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/  and https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with React or Bootstrap, so remove both from the equation: what happens if you just put that `<i....>` in your HTML file. No app, no loading things beyond just the fontawesome CSS. Simple HTML file, loaded with dev tools open to see if you get errors. Remember to run through the [mcve] exercise: it's there for _you_ to focus in your problem and find out exactly what's going wrong. And almost always, you end up finding out how to fix it once your code is as minimal as it can get, but in the rare cases you don't, you have the perfect code to put in a post.

Comment: the best way is to use material-ui icons in your react app. its easy and attractive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap last version doesn't work in my latest project. I change Bootstrap version and it solved my problem. Can you try to this in your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Instead of this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I cannot directly answer your question of "why". But if you just want it to work, i can recommend the npm-package "react-icons". Here you have direct access to many many icon-sets like Bootstrap icons or Font Awesome.

[React Icons page](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons)

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is change `f` to `fas` or `fab` according to the category the icons falls under.

You can check them at https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/free/

And

I don't think there is any font-awesome icons with name `fa-trash-o` and `fa-trash-heart`

Comment: is Bootstrap, not fontawesome